# Warning : Unexpected version number in 'available' attribute for non-specific platform '*'

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit, swift5, xcode10.2

I have this snippet code :

```
@available(*, deprecated:3.0, message:"Use activate().")
public func install() {
    self.activate()
}
```

And since i've upgraded to **swift5** and **xcode 10.2** i get below warning :

> Unexpected version number in 'available' attribute for non-specific
>   platform '*'

And fixed with :

> Replace ':3.0' with ''

What is this warning? what does it say?

Comment: I actually experienced the same thing when I was migrating to Swift 5. But such kind of warning went away after completely updating what needs to be updated, clean, and build.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html) states that the asterisk cannot be used with Swift version numbers, but perhaps this wasn't enforced before Swift 5?

The equivalent attribute would be:

```
@available(swift, deprecated:3.0, message:"Use activate().")
```

Even better would be:

```
@available(swift, deprecated:3.0, renamed:"activate()")
```

Comment: In my case, this is inside a 3rd party library, and I cannot update the source code for this library as it is no longer maintained.. Is there a workaround where by such enforcement that * cannot be used, can be given an exception?